# Auto Scheduling an activity in java using schedular annotation

Tags: java

I am using Schedular in order to schedule an activity. I am using @schedule annotation. I want that activity to be performed at 12.00 mid night. I have the following annotation. Can any tel me what would be the values of hour, minute and second?

```
 @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="0", persistent=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need any parameters as [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) says:

> All elements of this annotation are optional. If none are specified a
>   persistent timer will be created with callbacks occuring every day at
>   midnight in the default time zone associated with the container in
>   which the application is executing.

So, this should be enough:

```
@Schedule(persistent=false)
```